# How do i call a method in a graphics lab

Tags: java

Here is the code im using to make the background for a graphic but when I call it it won't compile

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.*;

class Background
{
    public static void showBackground(Graphics g)
    {
     drawWall(Graphics g);
     drawTable(Graphics g);
     drawTank(Graphics g);
    }
    
    private static void drawWall(Graphics g)
    {
     Expo.setColor(g,Expo.tan);
     Expo.fillRectangle(g,0,0,1000,650);
    }
    
    private static void drawTable(Graphics g)
    {
     Expo.setColor(g,Expo.brown);
     Expo.fillRectangle(g,125,450,175,650);
     Expo.fillRectangle(g,250,450,300,650);    
     Expo.fillRectangle(g,700,450,750,650);
     Expo.fillRectangle(g,825,450,875,650);
     Expo.fillPolygon(g,125,450,225,300,775,300,875,450);
    }
    
     private static void drawTank(Graphics g)
    {
     Expo.setColor(g,Expo.blue);
     Expo.fillRectangle(g, 250,75,750,400);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it won't compile it would be giving you an error. What is the error?

Comment: But, just guessing, it doesn't know what `Expo` is?